# Shiny filtering dates causing an error but unsure what it is exactly

Tags: r, datetime, shiny

Here is an example of my data
$Date and $DateTime are POSIXct format

```
# A tibble: 30,605 x 1
   cleandata$Date      $DateTime           $Site.Name   $DO $Salinity $Turbidity $Temperature
   <dttm>              <dttm>              <fct>      <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>        <dbl>
 1 2019-07-17 00:00:00 2019-07-17 11:30:00 SOUTHREF   107        36.0       0.6          8.20
 2 2019-07-17 00:00:00 2019-07-17 12:00:00 DIFF B      96.1      35.5       1.05        25.5 
 3 2019-07-17 00:00:00 2019-07-17 12:00:00 SOUTHREF    99.7      36.1       0.63         8.25
 4 2019-07-17 00:00:00 2019-07-17 12:30:00 DIFF B      96.8      35.5       1.19        25.5 
 5 2019-07-17 00:00:00 2019-07-17 12:30:00 SOUTHREF    99.5      36.0       0.66         8.01
 6 2019-07-17 00:00:00 2019-07-17 13:00:00 DIFF B      98        35.5       0.93        25.5 
 7 2019-07-17 00:00:00 2019-07-17 13:00:00 SOUTHREF   100        36.1       0.62         7.56
 8 2019-07-17 00:00:00 2019-07-17 13:30:00 DIFF B      96.6      35.5       1.02        25.5 
 9 2019-07-17 00:00:00 2019-07-17 13:30:00 SOUTHREF    99.8      36.1       0.73         6.95
10 2019-07-17 00:00:00 2019-07-17 14:00:00 DIFF B      98.6      35.4       0.99        25.5
```

Here is my shiny ui and server script

```
ui<-fluidPage(
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Dashboard"),

  sidebarLayout(
    # Sidebar with a slider and selection inputs
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("variable", "Variables",
                  choices = c("DO","Salinity","Turbidity","Temperature")),
      hr(),
      selectInput("site","Sites",
                  choices =levels(cleandata$Site.Name)),
      hr(),
      sliderInput("slider_date", "Date:",
                    min = min(cleandata$DateTime),
                     max = max(cleandata$DateTime),
                  value = min(cleandata$DateTime))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("quality")
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  plotdata <- reactive({
    cleandata %>%
      select(Date, DateTime, Site.Name,!!!input$variable) %>% 
      filter(cleandata, DateTime >= input$slider_date[1], DateTime <= input$slider_date[2]) %>%
      filter(cleandata, Site.Name == input$site)
    return(cleandata)
      })
  output$quality <- renderPlot({
    plot(plotdata()$DateTime,plotdata()[input$variable])
  })
}




shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When I run the app instead of plotting I receive the error message Error: '&' not defined for "POSIXt" objects.

I am quite unsure what is going, I don't have any POSIXt objects, only POSIXct and I have not used the & symbol in my script at all yet it seems that is what is causing the error.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Several elements weren't working :

- You need your choose a range of date with the slider, so you must indicates a vector of 2 elements on the value parameter
- WHen you define plotdata, you return "cleandata" but not the filtered data. Just remove the `return(cleandata)`
- In the plot, you must have vectors as argument for x and y. To have a vector from the data, use double [[ ]] around your column name.

Now it should work.

```
library(shiny)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

ui<-fluidPage(
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Dashboard"),

  sidebarLayout(
    # Sidebar with a slider and selection inputs
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("variable", "Variables",
                  choices = c("DO","Salinity","Turbidity","Temperature")),
      hr(),
      selectInput("site","Sites",
                  choices =levels(cleandata$Site.Name)),
      hr(),
      sliderInput("slider_date", "Date:",
                  min = min(cleandata$DateTime),
                  max = max(cleandata$DateTime),
                  value = c(min(cleandata$DateTime),max(cleandata$DateTime)))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("quality")
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  plotdata <- reactive({
    cleandata %>%
      select(Date, DateTime, Site.Name,!!!input$variable) %>% 
      filter(DateTime >= input$slider_date[1], DateTime <= input$slider_date[2]) %>%
      filter(Site.Name == input$site)
  })
  output$quality <- renderPlot({
    plot(plotdata()$DateTime,plotdata()[[input$variable]])
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```